# How to print a date from an excel sheet if it is the same date as today with Python?

Tags: python, excel, datetime, openpyxl

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to automate excel using openpyxl. I'm importing datetime and I'd like my code to go through all the dates in one specific column and return a date if it's equal to date.today().

So far I've been trying to do something like this:

```
`present = date.today()
 for row in sheet.iter_cols(
                        min_col=3,
                        max_col=3,
                        min_row=2,
                        max_row=sheet.max_row,
                        values_only=True):
    if present == row:
        print(row)`
```

But it is not printing anything even though I fixed the date format in excel.

Comment: `sheet.iter_cols()` always returns a tuple of cells or, in this case, values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your column holds [dates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e) and not date-like text, the reason why no value is printed is that at each iteration you're comparing a tuple of [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) objects (*[made by openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/datetime.html)*) to a [`date`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) one, which is today's date.

```
(
    datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 12, 0, 0)
) == date.today() # this evalutes to False
```

So, even with `values_only=True`, you still have unpack the tuples (*by adding an inner loop*) and use the method [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) to compare to :

```
for col in sheet.iter_cols(
    min_col=3,
    max_col=3,
    min_row=2,
    max_row=sheet.max_row,
    values_only=True
):
    for val in col:
        if present == val.date() :
            print(val)
```

Comment: Also, I believe openpyxl types excel dates as `datetime.datetime` object, so the variable `present` should be set to something like `datetime.today().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)` for the comparison.

Comment: That would be an option too, but an easy one is to use the [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date). I'll include yours to the answer.

Comment: My point, and I may be wrong here, is that `date.today()` can't ever be equal to `datetime.datetime(whatever)`, that is being returned from excel, as they are two different types.

Comment: No, I think you missed a detail. `val` in my code is a `datetime` object.

Comment: AH! Yes. Thank you! I was like... this person is pretty certain, I'm overlooking something obvious.